# how to shift the android layout when admob is available?

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

i'm using this layout xml to show both my activity and the admob:
first i thought it will shift the upper layout when the admob is available, but it is not...
do you guys have any idea?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wonder"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#000"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.anim.list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
    myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
</LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: here's my RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.anim.list"
android:id="@+id/master"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wonder"
 >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/inf"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#000"
/>   
<ListView
android:id="@+id/auto"
android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
android:layout_below="@+id/inf"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" 
    myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: updated screenshot]

**SOLVED**

Sorry buddies, I use this layout to solve my problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/wonder">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/home_layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Put all your application views here, such as buttons, textviews, edittexts and so on -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="#000"                
    />        
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"                
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.anim.list"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14db7f475a6f8d"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I got it works! thanks!

Comment: why dont you use use Relative layout what you want to achieve can't be done using LinearLayout because the shift happens in down direction in case LL

Comment: hi, it's still doesn't work... i mean the listview should populate the rest of the layout if there's no ads, when ads available the ad should push the listview up... there's no different when i use relative or linear, it's just same...

Comment: nope thats not the case change your xml to using realive L and post it here then I will suggest you what changes you should make in it to achieve what you want

Comment: yup! i have post it! i want the admob keep at bottom of the layout, that's why i add alignparentbottom....

Comment: so whats problem in this layout what actually happens if you use this

Comment: the listview is on it's place(ok), the admob is on the bottom of all(ok), BUT if there's no ads the layout keep share it's space to admob, this make an empty space at the bottom of the layout and it looks very weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your adview from xml instead change it to linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_ad" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in your code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);            

AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "your key");          
Display d = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();    
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(d.getWidth(), 52);        
layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
```

This is how I implemented in my app

Comment: i've done it, and as you can see.... there's an empty space at the bottom of the layout...(screenshot) sorry :(

Comment: I don't understand..., this just a layout; how can it be so difficult like this...? so mean to me..

Comment: k I figure it out you must be setting some width in your code something like this RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(d.getWidth(), 52);

Comment: so, i need to replace d with adview..., and what it does for my activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and flag the upper view with layout:above="@+id/your_ad"